# Azure - How to ignore (not publish) specific files when publishing to Azure

Tags: azure

I found one about - [ignoring a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914279/ignore-files-in-windows-azure-virtual-application)

However, I do not want to publish some individual files or folders (inside web application) to Azure. For example InternalOnly.aspx, /LocalOnlyFolder/

Is there any way I can set a list of files or folders not to publish?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any file you dont want to publish, you just need to set the file property to "copy to output directory as DO NOT COPY". This way when you will package the application that particular file will not be part of package and will never be on Azure.

[image]

AS you can see the ASPX will not be in package:

[image]

Comment: AvkashChauhan - I do not see 'Build Action' for folder. Any luck? Thanks!

Comment: only for files. Please open all files in the folder and set their properties individualy. Once all files in the folder are set, the full folder will not be the part of package.

Comment: yeah, but i want it to copy to bin for local dev

Answer (score 0):

You could pull code from blob storage, rather than bundling with your deployment. This lets you control what's in your "deploy" container in an efficient manner.

Comment: David - Thank you for the comment. Those pages are aspx pages.