# Include/Exclude files when creating Azure package

Tags: azure

I am creating an azure package using Visual Studio (right click on azure project -> package). I would like to include and exclude some files in the package similar to this: [How do you include additional files using VS2010 web deployment packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages) What do I need to do to get this working for the azure package function?

Comment: After lot of struggle, I could get the Exclude files part working. I have provided detailed steps on a SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30948078)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure deployment package (CSPKG) file is different then regular VS publish package even though CSPKG file is actually a zip  file. You can rename CSPKG to zip and see what is inside however you can not add or delete files this way as your package will be corrupt.

The best way to add files to your CSPKG is to add those files in your VS project and then in those file properties set "copy local as true" means add these files to final output. This way when you build the CSPKG the files will be there.

Comment: This will not work because the file I want to exclude and the file I want to include have the same file name and path.

Comment: If your are using VS2010 to Windows Azure package creation then you will be adding file via IDE and if you are using CSPACK tool to build the package then you will drop the file in your role folder to be included. There is no other way around it. Why do you have such a HARD design with your project?

Comment: There is not an equivalent to CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage target for this process?

Comment: As Windows Azure Cloud Service Publish process does not support xcopy deployment this will not work.