# How can I include additional files in an Azure cloud services package when using VSTS?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I have a solution with a web project in it and a cloud project for deploying that web project as a `cspkg` file to a cloud service. This all works fine. However, I have a file that i **don't** want in the web project but I **do** want deployed with the `cspkg` file into the cloud service.

We use VSTS to build and deploy things, and I haven't figured out how to include extra files in the package within this system. I tried a Copy Files step but that doesn't get the file into the package, it does get it into the artifacts though. I tried other things I found online, like the PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn injection technique, but nothing seems to work.

Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure deployment package file (CSPKG) file is zipped and encrypted, there isn’t the better way to add additional files (More details: [Include/Exclude files when creating Azure package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193982/include-exclude-files-when-creating-azure-package)). But you can include the files in BeforeBuild target. For this way, you don’t need to include files to the web project.

For example:

1. Edit web project file (e.g. WebRole1.csproj)
2. Add BeforeBuild target before  tag.

Code:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Files\TT.txt">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to specify an absolute path in the Include attribute of the Content element? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Josh It is working fine for me, but just files are copied (exclude folder). Anyway, you can copy necessary files to a folder through TFS build or during BeforeBuild target (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx), then specify the related path.